# vb.net Getting expression expected using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MyList").Split(';')

Tags: vb.net, web-config

I am using VB.net and have a list of a key value array in my web.config as follows

```
<add key="MyList" value="itemsome;itemtop;itemred"/>
```

However, in my code, when I got to read in the values, I get an error trying with the split expression: expression expected

```
Dim MyList() As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MyList ").Split(';')
```

Can you tell me how to do it right?

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo but you are splitting your semi-colon delimited list with a comma. Also, there is an extra space after `MyList`.

Comment: All true, but they don't impact the problem.  I edited the question, to correct these.

Answer (score 0):

I was poking around some more and found the solution: using `Split(CChar(";"))`

```
  Dim UserAgentBotIgnoreList() As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("UserAgentBotIgnoreList").Split(CChar(";"))
```

Also, other users were not seeing this because they didn't have *option strict* on like I do.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `';'` instead of `";"`, which denotes a string/char to split it by. Try this:

```
Dim MyList() As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MyList").Split(";")
```

Comment: VS2010 - I may be getting the error because I have Option Strict on however.